# Size efficient way to transfer array of numbers as text

Tags: c#, text, numbers, transfer

Lets say I have a following array of numbers:
`1,5,500,994,6950,54,54,845,101,54046506452,5980,960406,55,680,68045,66540,321032`

What is the most size efficient way to transfer it with http post to a website which decodes it back to numbers?

If I transfer it as text `"1,5,500,994,6950,54,54,845,101,54046506452,5980,960406,55,680,68045,66540,321032"` then every 1 digit and separator take 1 byte which is a waste of data since I may use all following characters: `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, ., _, ~` allowed in http without percent encoding.

I can recalculate decimal numeral system to a 65 numeral system which uses `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._` and use `~` as a separator which would make it look like `b~f~hT~pt~bP8~2~2~na~bK~ULUhIQ~bBa~dGuF~3~kE~qg3~pWT~bk.-`. But in my program I use mostly numbers of length 3-5 characters. Therefore around 1/5 of data would be only separators. Isn't there a better solution?

This question is asked very generally on purpose since I am open to any creative solution.

Comment: the actual bytes(as int) converted to a base64 string? or some compression algorithm (deflate)?

Comment: Some compression algorithm. The program needs to know that it works only with numbers and therefore doesn't need to reserve `a-z, A-Z, -, ., _, ~` but it needs to be possible to decompress it back to array of numbers.

Comment: Are the numbers signed? What's the biggest value?

Comment: Huffman coding with a fixed table would probably work well.

Comment: @DaveBish in practice some would be negative and decimal but I can eliminate it with adding and multiplying with fix numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete code for compression and decompression of positive long integers based on h3n's idea of using 1 byte for 2 characters, thanks! It uses 15 numeral system: from 0000 to 1110 binary and 1111 (0xF) as a separator.

compression:

```
public List<byte> EncodeNumbers(List<long> input)
{
    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
    int bytes_i = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < input.Count; a++)
    {
        int buffer_i = 65;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_i];
        while (input[a] > 0)
        {
            buffer[--buffer_i] = (byte)(input[a] %15);
            input[a] /= 15;
        }
        for (int b = 0; b < 65 -buffer_i; b++)
        {
            if (bytes_i %2 == 0)
            {
                bytes.Add((byte)(buffer[b +buffer_i] << 4));
                bytes_i++;
            }else{
                bytes[bytes_i++ /2] += buffer[b +buffer_i];
            }
        }
        if (a +1 != input.Count)
        {
            if (bytes_i %2 == 0)
            {
                bytes.Add(0xF << 4);
                bytes_i++;
            }else{
                bytes[bytes_i++ /2] += 0xF;
            }
        }
        else if (bytes_i %2 != 0)
        {
            bytes[bytes_i++ /2] += 0xF;
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

decompression:

```
public List<long> DecodeNumbers(List<byte> input)
{
    List<long> numbers = new List<long>();
    int buffer_i = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[17]; // max long = 9223372036854775807 = 160E2AD3246366807 (17 chars)
    for (int a = 0; a < input.Count; a++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            byte value = (byte)((i == 0) ? input[a] >> 4 : input[a] & 0xF);
            if (value != 0xF)
            {
                buffer[buffer_i++] = value;
            }else{
                long number = 0;
                for (int b = 0; b < buffer_i; b++)
                {
                    number += buffer[buffer_i -1 -b] *(long)Math.Pow(15, b);
                }
                buffer_i = 0;
                numbers.Add(number);
            }
        }
    }
    if (buffer_i != 0)
    {
        long number = 0;
        for (int b = 0; b < buffer_i; b++)
        {
            number += buffer[buffer_i -1 -b] *(long)Math.Pow(15, b);
        }
        numbers.Add(number);
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

usage:

```
List<long> numbers = new List<long>{4,10,14,51,5990,922337203685477,64,4685746,56545674,94,1,65454677,665555,1234567890,55555,22,2,3,2,0,99999,99955500099955577,1,2,666,654154,654,58,56,69,7,55,5647,321,25,0,697,9,9,9,9,9,96,5,546,4,645545,64564564,5465498654,6476854,85849865,6478596743,6,6,1,2,3,3,3,548745,6647};

string s = "plain text:\r\n";
string str = "";
foreach (long val in numbers)
{
    str += val + "|";
}
s += str + "\r\n" + str.Length + " bytes\r\n\r\n";

List<byte> encoded = EncodeNumbers(numbers);
s += "compressed base64:\r\n";
str = Convert.ToBase64String(encoded.ToArray());
s += str + "\r\n" + str.Length + " bytes\r\n\r\n";

List<long> decompressed = DecodeNumbers(encoded);
str = "";
foreach (long val in decompressed)
{
    str += val + "|";
}
s += "decompressed:\r\n" + str + "\r\n" + str.Length + " bytes";

Clipboard.SetText(s);
```

output:

```
plain text:
4|10|14|51|5990|922337203685477|64|4685746|56545674|94|1|65454677|665555|1234567890|55555|22|2|3|2|0|99999|99955500099955577|1|2|666|654154|654|58|56|69|7|55|5647|321|25|0|697|9|9|9|9|9|96|5|546|4|645545|64564564|5465498654|6476854|85849865|6478596743|6|6|1|2|3|3|3|548745|6647|
278 bytes

compressed base64:
T6/vNvG5X3GXGSLIRS9E9ihYH05uQZ9k8fWy3qL9IwX3NbfWDxFtrxfy8/L/HpafNlXR4iHg2i8fLy5vzcVPLZ89879J9/OvGhfxZvGv8xf5+fn5+fZvXyZvT8tBX1oFOU8h7FcB74fhBPeAvuXyfbdDSPb28fLz8/P6yNDx6C8=
172 bytes

decompressed:
4|10|14|51|5990|922337203685477|64|4685746|56545674|94|1|65454677|665555|1234567890|55555|22|2|3|2|0|99999|99955500099955574|1|2|666|654154|654|58|56|69|7|55|5647|321|25|0|697|9|9|9|9|9|96|5|546|4|645545|64564564|5465498654|6476854|85849865|6478596743|6|6|1|2|3|3|3|548745|6647|
278 bytes
```

Theere is a little loss of data when numbers are close to maximum of long int due to data type conversion which can be seen on 99955500099955577 vs 99955500099955574.

Comment: nice solution indeed. This base15 optimization looks so obvious when you see it :-) Still didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to convert each of your 12 possible characters into a 4 bit number, like

```
byte[] fourBitArr = new byte[input.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
    switch (input[i])
    {
        case '0': fourBitArr[i] = 0x0; break;
        case '1': fourBitArr[i] = 0x1; break;
        case '2': fourBitArr[i] = 0x2; break;
        case '3': fourBitArr[i] = 0x3; break;
        case '4': fourBitArr[i] = 0x4; break;
        case '5': fourBitArr[i] = 0x5; break;
        case '6': fourBitArr[i] = 0x6; break;
        case '7': fourBitArr[i] = 0x7; break;
        case '8': fourBitArr[i] = 0x8; break;
        case '9': fourBitArr[i] = 0x9; break;
        case ',': fourBitArr[i] = 0xA; break;
        case '-': fourBitArr[i] = 0xB; break;
    }
}
```

Then I would create a `byte[]` and put 2 of your characters in each byte (by shifting 4 bits to the front):

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[(input.Length+1)/2];
for (int i = 0; i < byteArr.Length; i++)
{
    byteArr[i] = (byte)fourBitArr[2*i];
    if (fourBitArr.Length > 2 * i + 1)
        byteArr[i] += (byte)(fourBitArr[2 * i + 1] << 4);
    else
        byteArr[i] += (0xF << 4);
}
```

The resulting `byte[]` can be encoded with Base64. This should encode each byte (2 of your previous characters) with 1,33 characters.

```
string output = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArr);
```

Note that Base64 creates a string containing `+`, `/` and `=` which have special meaning in URLs. You can replace each of them with one of the following allowed characters `-._~`

The above algorithm shortens your example input

`1,5,500,994,6950,54,54,845,101,54046506452,5980,960406,55,680,68045,66540,321032`
to
`oaUFoJmklgVapEWKVBoQWgRkBUYlWomgaUBgWqWGoIZApWZFoCMBIw==`

This is not optimal, but not too far from the optimum, if you consider that the entropy of your input is ~3,5 bit per character, and the entropy of an URL encoded character is about 6,05 bit. The algorithm is optimizable by finding a way to make use of 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF as possible values for the `fourByteArr`.

**Bonus:**
code for reverting it to the original string:

```
byte[] byteArrReverse = Convert.FromBase64String(output);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in byteArrReverse)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        byte fourBit = (byte)((i == 0) ? b & 0xF : b >> 4);
        switch (fourBit)
        {
            case 0x0: sb.Append('0'); break;
            case 0x1: sb.Append('1'); break;
            case 0x2: sb.Append('2'); break;
            case 0x3: sb.Append('3'); break;
            case 0x4: sb.Append('4'); break;
            case 0x5: sb.Append('5'); break;
            case 0x6: sb.Append('6'); break;
            case 0x7: sb.Append('7'); break;
            case 0x8: sb.Append('8'); break;
            case 0x9: sb.Append('9'); break;
            case 0xA: sb.Append(','); break;
            case 0xB: sb.Append('-'); break;
        }
    }
}
string inputReverse = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: if you need any clarification on one of the steps, feel free to ask

Comment: Thanks! I posted my solution based on your idea. It uses 15 numeral system and 16th character as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

You could pack numbers using 2 bytes each 3 digits, including sign, dot and separator info.

In ASCII strings we can use the 7 least significant bits of each byte, taking care every byte needs to hold a value of 32 or higher. So for a set of 2 bytes we could name it as:

```
abcdefgh ijklmnop
```

bits a and i will be always zero.
bits h and p will be used to signal separations.
bcde will be the first digit
fgjk will be the second digit
lmno will be the third digit

to ensure every byte will host a value always 32 or higher, we could use this encoding

1st digit:

```
9 = 1111
8 = 1110
7 = 1101
6 = 1100
5 = 1011
4 = 1010
3 = 1001
2 = 1000
1 = 0111
0 = 0110
- = 0101
. = 0100
```

Second digit:

```
. = 0010
- = 1010
0 = 0110
1 = 1110
2 = 0001
3 = 1001
4 = 0101
5 = 1101
6 = 0011
7 = 1011
8 = 0111
9 = 1111
```

Third digit:
Any of the previous 2 forms, for example as the first digit. When using a 2 digits block, reading all bits zero in the third digit signals the third digit is not present.

bits h and p signals if you need to read additional bytes to build this number.

For a single digit:

```
0bcde000
```

For a 2 digits number:

```
0bcdefg1 0jk00000
```

For a 3 digits number:

```
0bcdefg1 0jklmno0
```

For a 4 digits number:

```
0bcdefg1 0jklmno1 0rstu000
```

and so on...

No bytes are used to separate each number, and you can include sign and decimal separator (as dot).

If most data are 3-5 chars, that would mean 2-4 bytes each data on average.

This way, your sample data would be as:

```
"1,5,500,994,6950,54,54,845,101,54046506452,5980,960406,55,680,68045,66540,321032"
```

48 bytes in total for 81 characters:

```
"8X[L⌂tgw0[ [ s6;N[-Qw1uY _}0ylSX_ clclW awS I/50"


00111000 (56)
01011000 (88)
01011011 01001100 (91 76)
01111111 01110100 (127 116)
01100111 01110111 00110000 (103 119 48)
01011011 00100000 (91 32)
01011011 00100000 (91 32)
01110011 00110110 (115 54)
00111011 01001110 (59 78)
01011011 00101101 01010001 01110111 00110001 01110101 01011001 00100000 (91 45 81 119 49 117 89 32)
01011111 01111101 00110000 (95 125 48)
01111001 01101100 (121 108)
01010011 01011000 (83 88)
01011111 00100000 (95 32)
01100011 01101100 (99 108)
01100011 01101100 01010111 00100000 (99 108 87 32)
01100001 01110111 01010011 01000000 (97 119 83 32)
01001001 00101111 00110101 00110000 (73 47 53 48)
```

Comment: are you sure that you can transfer all your resulting characters via HTTP POST request?

Comment: @h3n Ops, forgot that, only 84 of the 96 possible values are valid. I will rethink the encoding to see I can find a valid schema. Thanks for pointing it. In case I cannot, should I delete my answer?

Comment: With msb zero, 4 bits for 1st digit, 2 bits for 2nd digit and 1 bit for separator, I am using 12 * 4 * 2 = 96 possible values, and just 88 are valid for HTTP POST, so this method is not valid using 12 possible chars. Using just 11 (without sign or dot) that would give us 88 values, so possible but I guess that isn't a good solution.